# How to add image to view programmatically?

Tags: uiimage

Say you have a `UIImage *image` and a `UIView *v`

How would you display the image on top of the view programmatically?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to add the UIImage to the UIView then you need an UIImageView inbetween the UIView and UIImage, such as:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[iv setImage:image];
[v addSubview:iv];
```

Note that the above is just dummy code and I've created all UI elements with a zero frame.

Comment: Thank you. What method of `UIControler` should contain this code?

Comment: what about releasing v and iv too? don't you have to do that?

Comment: @hanumanDev Yes, if not using ARC you will need to release v & iv. The golden rule of memory management in ObjC being that you only release what you create. The example was arbitrary with not much attention paid to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add UIImage to UIView programatically you can directly add image to view, Such as:

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];

customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];

[self.view addSubview:customView];
```